# How to understand abstract in-place merge sort

Tags: sorting, merge, in-place

I can't understand merge sort in place. For instance, why can var I be bigger than var mid? It is impossible because 3 variables: lo means low, hi means high, and mid means the average?

So I can not see what is going to happen if i>mid.

```
public static void merge(Comparable[] a, int lo, int mid, int hi) {

int i = lo, j = mid + 1;
for (int k = 0; k <= hi; k++) {
    aux[k] = a[k];
}
for (int k = lo; k <= hi; k++) {
    if (i > mid) {
        a[k] = aux[j++];
    } else if (j > hi) {
        a[k] = aux[i++];
    } else if(less(aux[j],aux[i])){
        a[k] = aux[j++];
    } else {
        a[k] = aux[i++];
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In-place merge sort works like this: If your array is empty or has one element, it is sorted. If it has two elements, you can sort it easily by swapping as appropriate. If it has more than two elements, do this:

- split the array in half at the midpoint `mid`;
- call merge sort on the left half;
- call merge sort on the right half;
- merge the arrays by picking the smallest head element from the two sub-arrays until they are exhausted.

The code you posted is not the full merge sort; it is only the merge part. At this point you have two sorted sub-arrays. The two sub-arrays need to be copied so that you can fill the original array with sorted values.

In this implementation, the sub-arrays are stored in one contiguous array, `aux`:

```
   lo         A         mid     B       hi
    +---+---+---+---+---++---+---+---+---+
    | 1 | 5 | 6 | 8 | 9 || 2 | 3 | 4 | 7 |
    +---+---+---+---+---++---+---+---+---+
    i ->                 j ->
```

Here, `i` is the index into `A`, which runs from 0 to `mid` inclusively. `j` is the index into `B`, which runs from `mid+1` to `hi` inclusively. The governing index `k` of the loop is a count of merge operations; there's one for every iteration.

All integer values are array indices; they don't represent values like averages. The merge algorithm relies on the sub-arrays being sorted.

To annotate your merge loop:

```
for (int k = lo; k <= hi; k++) {
    if (i > mid) {                      // A is exhausted, ...
        a[k] = aux[j++];                // ..., take B[j]
    } else if (j > hi) {                // B is exhausted, ...
        a[k] = aux[i++];                // ..., take A[i]
    } else if(less(aux[j], aux[i])) {   // B[j] < A[i], ...
        a[k] = aux[j++];                // ..., take B[j]
    } else {                            // A[i] <= B[j], ...
        a[k] = aux[i++];                // ..., take A[i]
    }
}
```

Here, "take" means "append to merges array and advance the appropriate array counter".

Comment: I got it ,but I wonder that ,when var I is increseing , it will stop before var  mid ,so var I will never bigger than mid

Comment: Yes, that's true. `aux[mid - 1]` is the last element of `A` and `aux[mid]` is the first element of `B`.

Comment: (In C, it is usual to describe a range with an inclusive lower bound and an exclusive upper bound. That matches the fact that an array has an element 0, but that the index ´n` is just out of bouns for an array of `n` elements. In my opinion it is a poor design choice to make `hi` the last index of the array and not one index beyond that. If `hi` were the exclusive upper bound, the bound of the two arrays were simply `[lo, mid)` and `[mid, hi)`. Plus we wouldn't have to write the unidiomatic ´<=` in the loop condition.)

Comment: Not too familiar with Java, but I think indexing works the same as in C or C++. But I see what you mean: My explanation above was one off: `aux[mid]` is the last element of `A` and the first element of `B` is `aux[mid + 1]`. So both `mid` and `high` are inclusive bounds. Sorry about that.

Comment: Thank you very much ,you inpsire me about the truth of in place merge sort,and only one question to be solved

Comment: @MOehm are you sure you don't have a typo, "..., B[i]" should be "...B[j]" ?

Comment: @Celeritas: You mean in the comment, where it should be `take B[j]`. Yes, that's a typo.

Comment: @MOehm aren't you going to fix it?